# The weird thing of my Magento template?

Tags: magento, translation

The customer login page of h1 html code is

```
<h1 class="translate-inline" 
translate="[{shown:'Create an Account',translated:'Create an  Account',original:'Create an Account',location:'Heading level 1',scope:'Mage_Customer'}]">
Create an Account
</h1>
```

and there is

```
<span class="translate-inline-title translate-inline" 
translate="[{shown:'Create New Customer Account',translated:'Create New Customer Account',original:'Create New Customer Account',location:'Page title',scope:'Mage_Customer'}]">
TITLE
</span>
```

under the `body` html code.

I found all of those will have those useless code if it is generated by `echo $this->__()`. How do I remove the useless code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Magento's `inline translations` is enabled. You can disable it in the admin under `System > Configuration > Developer > Translate Inline > Enabled for frontend`